# How do I upload a "large" GeoJSON file to a Mapbox Dataset?

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I have a 17.7mb GeoJSON file. I tried creating a new Mapbox Dataset with it through the web UI but got an error saying for files over 5mb you have to use the [Datasets API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/datasets/#create-a-dataset).

I then tried to use the API:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/${MAPBOX_USERNAME}?access_token=${MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
  -d @ne_10m_coastline.json \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

But got the following error:

```bash
{"message":"request entity too large"}
```

I don't see anything in the API docs about file size restrictions, and as GeoJSON files go, 17.7mb is pretty small.

How can I create a Mapbox Dataset with my file?